# How to change swimlane orientation in Visio BPMN diagram using VBA

Tags: vba, visio

Visio 2013 contains a stencil for the BPMN diagram type. This stencil has a "Pool / Lane" master. When you drop it on a drawing, a new lane appears. Then you can go to the "Cross-functional Flowchart" ribbon and change its orientation with the "Orientation" option button, which offers a selection of vertical and horizontal orientations. How can I do the same manipulation in VBA?

I've tried to record the respective macro in Visio macro recorder. Surprisingly, the recorded macro contains no code for this manipulation.

Comment: Upvoting for visibility. I'm having this same issue almost two years later. The solution that worked for Visio 2010 that is listed at the following link does not appear to work, since the stencil for Pool / Lane no longer has separate objects for vertical and horizontal orientation: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/d158f3cb-3804-4ff0-a730-246896b3dd46/visio-2010-manage-flowchart-swimlane-via-code?forum=officegeneral

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i open shapesheet window, and change vertical/horizontal orientation. i find cells which changed with orientation 
[image]

Comment: Sorry, when i changed these cells orientation not changed :(